# UDP NAT Hole Punching on separate UdpClient objects

Tags: c#, .net-core

I believe I am having an issue with NAT hole punching via `UdpClient` objects. I have a simple class that looks like:

```
class UdpConnection
{
    UdpClient   udpSend         { get; set; }
    UdpClient   udpRecv         { get; set; }
    IpEndPoint  TargetEndPoint  { get; set; }

    UdpConnection(IPEndPoint targetEndPoint)
    {
        TargetEndPoint = targetEndPoint;
    }

    void SendTo(byte[] bytes)
    {
        udpSend.Client.SendTo(bytes, TargetEndPoint);
    }

    void TryToConnect   () { // ... // }
    void WaitForConnect () { // ... // }
}
```

A client will use one of these objects and call `TryToConnect()`. The client will then use `UdpConnection.udpRecv.Client.SendTo()` to send a Hello packet to the server and then sleep for a second waiting for a response. When the Hello is acknowledge it then uses `UdpConnection.udpRecv` only for listening, updates the `UdpConnection.udpSend` object to use the target port given by the server to send further data and is then considered connected.

A server uses a dedicated `UdpClient` object to listen on for new connections. When it receives a new remote address it creates a new `UdpConnection` object with the new address, creates an Acknowledgement packet providing the specific port for this new connection to send data to and then listen on that port and send the Acknowledgement packet.

This all works when ran locally but the client will fail to receive the Acknowledgement packet when ran remotely. What makes me think this is a NAT Hole punching issues is that if I send the acknowledgement back on the server's listening port, the one that received the new connection, the client receives it. This makes me feel like I am missing something.

Where have I gone wrong? Is it that I am attempting to hand off the response to a new `UdpClient` instead of the one the client connected to? Do I have to handle the whole handshake on the Listening Port until the client uses its new dedicated port on the server?

Comment: How is this Off Topic? This feels like a specific programming problem (changing socket objects basically) I have run into.

Comment: As a note, using the listener until the client redirects to the dedicated port does work.. but this still just seems odd that the punching is attached to the software instead of the socket.. I would like to know what is going on here if anyone is aware of the underneaths of this.